# How to return new allocated object in function on Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

How to return new allocated object in function?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"liteCell"];
    [cell.textLabel setText:@"Lite"];
    return cell; // Object returned to caller as an owning reference (single retain count transferred to caller)
}
```

Object leaked: object allocated and stored into 'cell' is returned from a method whose name ('tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:') does not start with 'copy', 'mutableCopy', 'alloc' or 'new'.  This violates the naming convention rules given in the Memory Management Guide for Cocoa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return an autoreleased object in this case, so the solution is

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault] autorelease];
```

Oh, and a better way is to also use `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]`, like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (nil == cell) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: of course this is assuming that you're not using ARC. Under ARC you would just return the cell and ARC would implicitly do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 5 you need to check wether cell is already instantiated, if not you need to instantiate the cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (nil == cell) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }

    return cell;
}
```

Under iOS 6+ you just need to register the Cell you want for the table view like that:

```
[tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

Then later on you can use:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

and will always receive a allocated cell so you can just write

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
```